# Merging two styles into one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a style for a `CustomTextbox` and I want to apply a solution I have found to add "Hint Text" aka "Placeholder" [here](http://www.techken.in/coding/c-wpf-create-textbox-placeholder-using-xaml-code/).
I'm pretty close to the final solution but seems that I have something missing on the merging, maybe someone with a better knowledge in WPF can see it.

```
<Style x:Key="placeHolder" TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="/UserInterface;component/Resources/Fonts/#Avenir LT Std 35 Light" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#FF414042" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        BorderBrush="#FF348781"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,4"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  Margin="0" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource placeHolder}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Utils:CustomTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             x:Name="textSource" 
                             Background="Transparent" 
                             Panel.ZIndex="2"
                             Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}"/>
                    <Utils:CustomTextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1" >
                        <Utils:CustomTextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Utils:CustomTextBox.Style>
                    </Utils:CustomTextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The result is:
[image]
But this is the expect:
[image]

Any kind of help would be greatful, also if there is a better way to do this would be nice to hear it as I'm willing to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be amazing if you can explain the downvote, instead of just downvoting without given a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was missing another BaseOn Attribute on the inner style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource placeHolder}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Utils:CustomTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         x:Name="textSource" 
                         Background="Transparent" 
                         Panel.ZIndex="2"
                         Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}"/>
                    <Utils:CustomTextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1" >
                        <Utils:CustomTextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Utils:CustomTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource placeHolder}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Utils:CustomTextBox.Style>
                    </Utils:CustomTextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```